# 5.15.0-1051-realtime kernel release notes

Tags: kernel, 22.04, realtime, ubuntu-pro

On my 22.04.3 LTE machine I have upgraded the kernel from 5.15.0-1050-realtime to 5.15.0-1051-realtime. Where could find I a document summarizing the fixes and changes between two subsequent kernel versions?

Comment: @Terrance That's an Ubuntu pro thing https://ubuntu.com/real-time which means it's out of support here If I'm not mistaken ... But, `apt changelog ...` should work on the subscribed system I think.

Comment: @Raffa Ah, thank you!  That makes more sense now.  I use LivePatch which doesn't allow for real-time kernels.  And yes, I believe that you are correct in them being out of support here.